# iPhone UITableViewCell selectionStyle when editing?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I know I can change the `selectionStyle` of a `UITableViewCell` to make it highlight *blue or grey* when selected, but how can I change this when in editing mode?

I don't want the cell to normally by selectable, only when in editing mode, like the Alarm part of the Clock application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I dont want the cell to normally by
>   selectable, only when in editing mode

On your `UITableView` object, set its `allowsSelection` property to `NO`, and set its  `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` property to `YES`.